# mongodb connections current vs active

Tags: mongodb, connections

When I use the command 'db.serverStatus().connections' I don't understand the meaning of 'current'. The documentation defines it as 'The number of incoming connections'. [Doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/)

My application is a chat, when I create the socket connection I create a mongodb connection

```
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url)
await mongoClient.connect()
const db = mongoClient.db(Constants.DATABASE_NAME)
```

When I remove the socket connection (user exits) I remove the connection to mongodb

```
await resources.mongoClient.close()
```

After creating the connection I always use the 'db' object that is in memory, 'new MongoClient(url) is never called. Access to mongodb is:

```
const collection = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
const findResult = await collection.find({socketId:socketId}).toArray()
```

Before connecting:

```
"current" : 7,
"available" : 838853,
"totalCreated" : 28,
"active" : 1,
threaded : 7,
```

When I connect (and do some necessary queries to db: insert user, get list of rooms...) I get:

```
"current" : 10,
"available" : 838850,
"totalCreated" : 31,
"active" : 2,
threaded : 10,
```

When the user leaves the chat I close the socket and mongodb:

```
["current" : 7,
"available" : 838853,
"totalCreated" : 31,
"active" : 1,
threaded : 7,][1]
```

Why does current increase by 3? What does it mean?
The number of actual connections available is "available" / 3 ?
Is this behavior normal? do i do something wrong?